# fadeIn and fadeOut of images

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I found a good script that will work on my project
but can't figure out on how to make the images fadeIn and fadeOut with this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeId = $(".active").each(function(){
        $("#content" + $(this).attr("id").replace("tab","")).show();
    });
   $(".tabs a").click(function() {
      var $tabs =$(this).closest(".tabs"); 
      $("#content" +$tabs.attr("data-lastContent")).hide();
      $(this).closest(".tabs").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active")
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
       $tabs.attr("data-lastContent", id);
      $("#content" + id).show();

   });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/446/

Comment: It is preferred you conduct a search before asking a question on [so]. Replace `.show()` with [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and `.hide()` with [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). See linked pages for options syntax.

Comment: What have you tried?  You've provided a working "tabs" script but not the changes you've tried.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/451/

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain your fade in and fade out speed in hide() and show() method.
It may be work for you as mentioned in below link example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hKMFb/450/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeId = $(".active").each(function(){
        $("#content" + $(this).attr("id").replace("tab","")).show(1000);
    });
   $(".tabs a").click(function() {
      var $tabs =$(this).closest(".tabs"); 
      $("#content" +$tabs.attr("data-lastContent")).hide(1000);
      $(this).closest(".tabs").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
       $tabs.attr("data-lastContent", id);
      $("#content" + id).show(1000);

   });

});
```

You can also used `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` for animation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeId = $(".active").each(function(){
        $("#content" + $(this).attr("id").replace("tab","")).fadeIn(1000);
    });
   $(".tabs a").click(function() {
      var $tabs =$(this).closest(".tabs"); 
      $("#content" +$tabs.attr("data-lastContent")).fadeOut(1000).hide();
      $(this).closest(".tabs").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
       $tabs.attr("data-lastContent", id);
      $("#content" + id).fadeIn(1000);

   });
});
```

Comment: this is good but it resize my div every time it changes image and it creates animation queues